# Why does oil change the color of salmorejo?

Tags: oil, tomatoes, spanish-cuisine

We did a few experiments last year with [salmorejo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salmorejo), a cold soup made of very ripe tomatoes and bread, very similar to [gazpacho](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gazpacho).

We noticed that while blending, the salmorejo would turn pink. This is because the tomatoes get into contact with oxygen. We don't like the colour/taste of the pink salmorejo. Adding more oil to the soup would miraculously restore the colour/taste.

So, there's the question: why does adding more oil ([EVOO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EVOO)) restore the colour of the tomato soup?

Comment: it depends also in the variety of oil. I mean arbequina is going to give you a different color from picual or cornicabra. The "cloroplastos" makes the difference. Cheers from Córdoba

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When tomatoes are fried, you can see that the oil becomes coloured red - so at least some of the colour components are preferentially soluble in oil.

I will hazard a guess that, under the circumstances mentioned, the oil coats the tomato particles, and some of the colour migrates into it to give a red surface. Because the oil forms a coating, that coat will inhibit oxidation.  The oil will also improve the mouth feel of the soup.

Just the way I see it ...

Answer (score 1):

"blending", you didn't use a food processor did you?

You must chop and fold by hand if you want good colour, and to some degree taste

Comment: Yes, we do use the hand blender.

Comment: That's an easy fix then. Chop and blend by hand. No significant colour change, and a better looking soup